# PHP in JavaScript using document.write();

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have quite a script that adds items into a table. I need to pull information from a MySQL database based on the UPC that is passed through the JavaScript.

I tried: `document.write("<?php echo '375'; ?>");` just to see if it would work, and once the script got to that line, the page refreshed and displayed a blank white page.

The full JavaScript is below:

```
//setup before functions
var field = document.getElementById("UPC");
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 1000;  //time in ms, 1 seconds

//on keyup, start the countdown
$('#UPC').keyup(function(){
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$('#UPC').keydown(function(){
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});

function doneTyping () {
//user is "finished typing," do something
if (field.value.length != 0) {
    document.getElementById("noScan").className="hidden";
    document.getElementById("checkout").className="";
    document.getElementById("void").className="";
    var upc=document.getElementById("UPC").value;
    var price = document.write("<?php echo '375'; ?>");
    var weight = parseInt(document.getElementById("weight").value);
    var table=document.getElementById("ScannedItems");
    var total = weight * price;
    var row=table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6=row.insertCell(5);
    cell1.innerHTML=upc;
    cell2.innerHTML="Example Description";
    cell3.innerHTML = "$" + price.toFixed(2);
    cell4.innerHTML = weight + " lbs";
    cell5.innerHTML = "$" + total.toFixed(2);
    cell5.setAttribute('data-total', total); // caches the total into data
    cell6.innerHTML="<a class='add'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus' style='padding-right:15px;'></span></a><a class='delete'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span></a>";
    field.value ='';

    var total = cell5.getAttribute('data-total');
    var salesTax = Math.round(((total / 100) * 8.25)*100)/100;
    var totalAmount = (total*1) + (salesTax * 1);

    document.getElementById('displaysubtotal').innerHTML="$" + (Math.floor(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('displaytax').innerHTML="$" + salesTax;
    document.getElementById('displaytotal').innerHTML="$" + totalAmount;
}
   }


    // Duplicate a scanned item
    var $table = $('#ScannedItems');
    $('#ScannedItems').on('click', '.add', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').clone();

$table.append($tr);
    });

    // Remove a line item
    var $table = $('#ScannedItems');
    $('#ScannedItems').on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
```

I must figure out how to get information from my database for this project or it is going to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript executes on the client side, PHP executes on the server side. So PHP is done executing before JS starts.

So in order to fetch new data, you'll need to initiate a call to your server. You can do this by either refreshing the page with the results you need or by creating an [AJAX call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

To make it more clear, take a closer look at the example you gave. View the source code in your browser. It will come out as `document.write("375");`. That's because PHP echo'ed the string '375' into your JS code on the server side before sending the page to the browser (which is where the JS code executes).

PHP can generate JS code, but JS cannot generate PHP code (in the usual sense).

Comment: Ok so I have re-created my javascript to include an ajax. Now how do I get the pulled data from the database back into the javascript to display it in the table?

Comment: Whatever you echo in your PHP code will be sent back as the AJAX response. I recommend you go through a tutorial on AJAX (trust me, it's worth it...you'll use AJAX again). For this usage, I would recommend that you output your response from PHP in JSON format. Then it will be received by your AJAX call response as a JS object/array that you can loop through to create the rows in your table.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is executed on the server before serving generate HTML to a clients browser. Any PHP code inserted by the javascript on the client will not run.

If you want to have code inserted dynamically from PHP, you might investigate how to use AJAX calls to run a separate PHP server-side script and insert the returned content.

Answer (score -2):

You can perfectly use php inside javascript, because php executes before javascript reachs the browser. So the browser receives the page with the php result executed which builds the javascript sentence... the browser doesnt know that the javascript sentence was writen by you or by the php server.

```
document.write("<?php echo '375'; ?>");
```

try changing it to...

```
document.write("<?php echo("375"); ?>");
```

the "" are first seen by php server so the above should work.

or just in case you can escape the "

I also have this piece of code fully functional:

```
frameDoc.document.write sentence

<?php 
echo("frameDoc.document.write(\"");
require('secciones/seccion_head2.html');
echo("\");"); 
?>

frameDoc.document.write sentence
```

**BUT!!! inside the required html you cant use more than one line!!!!**

Comment: Java is not the same thing as JavaScript. The other answers already said that the PHP code will be run first and the output will be sent to the browser along with the JavaScript code. Including HTML by using PHP and document.write() is quite a bad idea. And to top it off: the question was running PHP from JavaScript, not outputting JavaScript from PHP.

Comment: Well i still think that the user wants to generate javascript using php, but all other answers just see the easy answer and say "you cant"... but the exact thing he needs is to generate different javascript according to some situation he detects using php... by the way just in case i edited my answer to be more friendly  :)